# Conditional expectation $E(Z_1+...+Z_N | \min(Z_1,...,Z_N) )$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $Z_1,Z_2,...$ be i.i.d. random variables with density: $$f(x)=\frac{\lambda^{\theta} \theta }{(\lambda+x)^{\theta+1}} \mbox{ for } x>0,$$ where $\theta>1, \lambda>0$. Let $N$ be independent of $Z_1,Z_2,..$ with geometric distibution $$P(N=n)=(1-q)q^{n-1} \mbox { for } n=1,2,...$$ where $q \in (0,1)$. $$E(Z_1+...+Z_N | \min(Z_1,...,Z_N)=t)=?$$ I thought that it would be possible to use tower property to introduce $N$ as a condition and then use Bayes' theorem, but I'm not sure if there is a proper inclusion of $\sigma$-algebras to use the tower property. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can always condition on anything you want, for example in this case: $$ E[sum | min=t] = E[E[sum | min = t, N]|min=t] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Pr[N=n|min=t]E[sum|min=t, N=n]$$ There is also some "symmetry" in the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but could you explain how you got these equalities? I don't see it.

Comment: This is the "tower property."  We have $E[X] = E[E[X|N]]$ for any random variables $X$ and $N$. In this case, you can envision it as living in a world where $\min=t$, so everything we do is conditioned on this. So I am really using $E[X|min=t] = E[E[X|N, min=t]|min=t]$.

Comment: If you want to think in terms of sigma-algebras, we have $E[X|\mathcal{G}_1] = E[E[X|\mathcal{G}_2]|\mathcal{G}_1]$ when $\mathcal{G}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{G}_2$.  In this case $\mathcal{G}_1 = \sigma(min)$ and $\mathcal{G}_2 = \sigma(min, N)$.  Using the formula from my very first comment, can you solve the problem?  Perhaps you can post an answer to your own question (that is a standard thing to do after some hints).

Comment: Thanks! Now I get it. Could you also explain the last equality?

Comment: To get quickly to the answer, note that, with $S=Z_1+\ldots+Z_N$ and $M=\min(Z_1,\ldots,Z_N)$, $$E(S\mid M=t,N)=t+(N-1)E(Z\mid Z>t),$$ hence $$E(S\mid M=t)=t+(E(N)-1)E(Z\mid Z>t).$$ Can you compute $E(N)$ and $E(Z\mid Z>t)$?

Comment: @Did : It is not clear how you got the last line.  I believe you need $E[N|M=t]$ (rather than $E[N]$), since we are living in a world where $M=t$.

Comment: Anyway my interpretation of rafalpw's last comment/question was not explaining how to compute $E[sum|min=t, N=n]$, but how I got the equality $E[sum|min=t] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} Pr[N=n|min=t]E[sum|min=t,N=n]$. But he seemed unresponsive to my 3-ways of explaining it, despite my efforts in the answer below. So perhaps rafalpw was indeed stuck on the conditional expectation part you computed.

Comment: @Michael Needs E(N|M=t)= you are absolutely right, this was careless of me (I am leaving my first comment on the site for educational purposes). OP unresponsive: unfortunately, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always condition on anything you want, in this example we have: 
$$ E[X|\min=t] = E[E[X|N, \min=t]|\min=t] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E[X|N=n,\min=t]Pr[N=n|\min=t] $$
and you can work the problem from this formula.

---

Three ways to understand this formula:

1) For a general random variable $X$, we have the "tower property" (also called "iterated expectations"): 
$$ E[X] = E[E[X|N]] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E[X|N=n]Pr[N=n] $$
Now, if we live in a world where $\min=t$ then everything in the above formula should be conditioned on "$\min=t$."

2) In terms of sigma-algebras, the tower property is $E[X|\mathcal{G}_1] = E[E[X|\mathcal{G}_2]|\mathcal{G}_1]$ whenever $\mathcal{G}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{G}_2$. In this example we have $\mathcal{G}_1 = \sigma(\min)$ and $\mathcal{G}_2 = \sigma(\min, N)$.

3) Define $1\{N=n\}$ as an indicator function that is 1 if $N=n$, and 0 else. Then with prob 1 we have: 
$$ 1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1\{N=n\}$$
Thus, with prob 1: 
$$ X = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X \cdot 1\{N=n\}$$ 
Now take conditional expectations of both sides, given $min=t$:
\begin{align}
E[X|\min=t] &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E[X \cdot 1\{N=n\} | \min=t] \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E[X|N=n, \min=t]Pr[N=n|\min=t]
\end{align}